# error 'user.findOneAndUpdate is not a function' but data updated

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i'm trying to use findOneAndUpdate for change password on mongoose, it's work, database updated
but error message show

> "error": "user.findOneAndUpdate is not a function"

this my routes

```
router.post('/changepass', async (req, res) => {
  const { phone, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({phone},{password})
    await user.findOneAndUpdate();

    res.send({ user });
  } catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
    res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

and this my userSchema

```
userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate',  function(next) {
  const update = this.getUpdate()
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(update.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      this.getUpdate().password = hash;
      return next();
    })
  })
});
```

please help me, i'm stuck for hours on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing this line `await user.findOneAndUpdate();` This line is causing the error and as per official docs it should be not there

```
   router.post('/changepass', async (req, res) => {
  const { phone, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({phone},{password})

    res.send({ user });
  } catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
    res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

here is doc reference - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html